# SQL Server Select queries very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have `SQL Server 2005` on `Windows Server 2003`. It was fine 2 days before but now queries are taking a lot of time. Example:

```
Select * from Table --[table has around 6000 records]
```

There are other databases too which are working fine but this is problem with one database.

I tried to `DBCC DBREINDEX` but it took 18 hours & still running. Finally, I had to cancel it.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Quite sure, DB is corrupted. Export data, drop database, recreate database, import data.

Comment: I just checked that database is returning small queries like [ select top 100 * from table] but it stuck if I write [select top 1000 * from table] . Is database corrupt?

Comment: As I said. This happens quite regularily with MSSQL2005, I have seen this lots of times.

Comment: WHat should I do now? Can this database work with MSSQL2008?

Comment: As I said: Export data, drop database, recreate database, import data.

Comment: @EugenRieck - Terrible Advice. My first thought would be a long running open transaction somewhere holding an open lock on something between rows 100-1000. The advice should be to look at `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see what the delay is.

Comment: I work with SQL Server for more than 1 decade and i never had a corrupted DB. The only possible way this can happen: the hardware is broken.

Comment: @MartinSmith - well, I have seen this many times, and the OP tells us the terrible advice fixed the problem. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @EugenRieck - It may well have solved their problem but if they had taken some basic diagnostic steps they almost certainly wouldn't have had to do it. There is nothing in the question that indicates anything other than an open transaction holding a lock to me.

Comment: Again: Let's agree to disagree. Problem solved, OP is happy.

Comment: @EugenRieck it solved the symptom ... not the problem

Comment: @EugenRieck [here is the evidence](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30276/simple-queries-run-slowly)

Comment: @EugenRieck Now the OP is doing the correct diagnosis, [he's identified the real problem](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30466/select-blocking-issue). No surprises, it's exactly what Martin suggested.

Comment: @EugenRieck since the OP is back, you want to give it another go? Something tells me you're wrong on your diagnosis ...

Comment: @EugenRieck - this is purely brilliant. If you cut your head, off course the worse headache would go away! Wouldn't you better know why it hurts and get the right pill? Less spectacular solution, but almost always works.